# Is there any way to detect client connected/disconnected?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm looking for a technology in scope of ASP.NET Core for replacement of my WCF application, the server needs to know each client's connection status(in case client PC shutdown or network problems).

as far as I know signalR is based on WebSocket in Transportation layer and Hubs API provides OnConnectedAsync and OnDisconnectedAsync virtual methods to manage and track connections, whereas web api or gRPC is based on HTTP protocol which is stateless.

**so my question: is there any way or technology in ASP.NET Core that supports detecting client connected/disconnected ?**

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, at present Asp.net core SignalR doesn't have the build-in method to check whether the group is empty or if there any clients exists in the group. And from the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-5.0), we could also find that:

*Group membership isn't preserved when a connection reconnects. The connection needs to rejoin the group when it's re-established. It's not possible to count the members of a group, since this information is not available if the application is scaled to multiple servers.*

To detect clients connect or disconnect, as a workaround, in the hub method, you could define a global variable to store the group name and the online count, or you could store the user information (user name, group name, online status etc.) in the database.

In the OnConnectedAsync method, you could add the user to the group and calculate the online count or change the user's online status, in the OnDisconnectedAsync method, remove users from the group and change the online user count. Create a custom method to check/get the online user count.

code like this (in this sample code, I use the Login user name to create groups, you could change it based on your scenario):

```
[Authorize]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private static Dictionary<string, int> onlineClientCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    { 
        var IdentityName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, IdentityName);

        int count = 0;
        if (onlineClientCounts.TryGetValue(IdentityName, out count))
            onlineClientCounts[IdentityName] = count + 1;//increment client number
        else
            onlineClientCounts.Add(IdentityName, 1);// add group and set its client number to 1


        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    { 
        
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }

    public async Task SendMessageToGroup(string sender, string groupname, string message)
    { 
        //check if group contains clients or not via the global variable or check database.

        await Clients.Group(groupname).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", sender, message);
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        var IdentityName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, IdentityName);

        int count = 0;
        if (onlineClientCounts.TryGetValue(IdentityName, out count))
        {
            if (count == 1)//if group contains only 1client
                onlineClientCounts.Remove(IdentityName);
            else
                onlineClientCounts[IdentityName] = count - 1;
        } 

        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I'm actually looking for a asp.net core framework other than signalR.

Comment: Hi @Chris, As far as I know, the Asp.net Core doesn't contain this framework, you could consider using the above method as a workaround.